# How can I pass a 50d vector to fit Naive-Bayes model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm performing sentiment analysis and am new to word embedding. I've converted my phrases to 50d vectors using GloVe word embedding and want to pass these as training data but keep getting

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-85-33202bf88193> in <module>
      1 bnbclf = BernoulliNB()
----> 2 bnbclf.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train, sample_weight = [cw[i] for i in y_train])
```

My vectors are of the form:

```
X_train[0]

array([ 13.81449103,   8.60164096,  -9.76383901,  -2.36460596,
        12.91351991,  12.32445506,  -9.92880224,  -7.15983607,
        -0.78202473,   3.11839001,  -2.55677491,   2.92986998,
        -6.47585791,  -6.82789405,  11.60826143,   1.44951305,
         6.06078495,   4.16923777, -14.08995277, -10.54117191,
         0.81230098,   4.05350507,   5.27667667,  -1.81203901,
         6.59123958, -52.43976641, -19.74524475,   5.28675767,
         6.99492514,  -7.60190205, 105.55067018,   1.80315194,
        -5.42133144, -11.38166397,   2.58026635,   0.24258623,
        -1.0791869 ,   2.17247699,  -0.54076034,  -4.01877102,
        -4.01617018,   5.05499033,  -3.4997439 ,   6.451917  ,
        -5.32425116,   2.22513228,  -3.29181632,   2.90443946,
        -1.06864398,  -3.32023967])
```

The code I'm running is:

```
bnbclf = BernoulliNB()
bnbclf.fit(X = X_train, y = y_train, sample_weight = [cw[i] for i in y_train])
```

Here are the class weights and y_train for the same:-

```
cw = {0:9. , 1:3., 2:1., 3:3.,4:8.}
```

```
y_train[1:5]
72290     2
151058    2
80065     2
148397    1
Name: Sentiment, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The error you're getting is raised in numpy when the function expects a single value but you're giving it an array-like object instead. There could be a shape mismatch or interpretation problem in your `cw` object or you're not iterating correctly. Can you display a few values of the object `cw` and `y_train` please so we can help better?

Comment: [This](https://pythonmachinelearning.pro/text-classification-tutorial-with-naive-bayes/) may help!